# How to align content to middle of container Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to align the card to the middle of the container (vertically and horizontally) but using text-align or vertical-align don't seem to work.

```css
.container-fluid {
  text-align: center;
}

.card {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 60%;
  padding: 20px;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-block">
                <p class="card-text">
                    "Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..." "There is no one who loves pain itself, who seeks after it and wants to have it, simply because it is pain..."
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thankfully, flexbox makes it easy to center content! You can adjust the height and width of the container as needed. I just used `width: 100%;` and `height: 500px;` for testing. Try the code below:

```css
.container-fluid {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}

.card {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 60%;
  padding: 20px;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-block">
                <p class="card-text">
                    "Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..." "There is no one who loves pain itself, who seeks after it and wants to have it, simply because it is pain..."
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```